# create additional columns with a set of formulas in r

Tags: r

I need to create many additional columns in my data frame. To achieve this, I'm doing the following to my data (var4 and var5). What are some ways to make this more elegant/fast considering a lot more columns that needs to be added ? I'm new to R and programming in general so any help/reading recommendation is welcome. Thanks

```
var1 <- 1
var2 <- 2
var3 <- 3

mtcars$var4 <- var1 * (var1^2 + var2^2)^(1/4)* mtcars$mpg / (1e-2*var3^(3/2)/(var3+100))

mtcars$var5 <- mtcars$hp/(4*0.01)
```

Comment: If there is no relationship between the new columns, then there is no way of simplifying it, we will need to create/compute each column manually.

Comment: You could simplify the math bits, for example instead of 4*0.01 use 0.04 ?

Comment: there is no direct relationship. ok then I'll just continue creating new columns like this way. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always clean up the syntax a little bit using `tidyverse` methods, e.g.

```
mtcars %<>% 
            mutate(var4 = var1 * (var1^2 + var2^2)^(1/4)*mpg / (1e-2*var3^(3/2)/(var3+100)), 
                   var5 = hp/(4*0.01))
```

This way you avoid multiple separate assignments and increase transparency by avoiding repeated subsetting with `$`. It is a question of style though. Note also the `%<>%` operator from the `magrittr` package.